# geoserver applied styles shuffled order

Tags: geoserver, style

I uploaded a multi columns table (GIS data) to Geoserver,

[image: shapefile with multiple columns]
and I created different styles for each column, and named them with number as initial and then column name like
So I see everything in order.

style Names:
00_f1
01_f2
02_f3
03_f4
04-f5

but Geoserver does not preserve the order and the selected styles will appear not ordered in Mapstore or even Openlayer preview of Geoserver.

[image: selected styles]

am I doing something wrong in here? or this is the feature / problem of Geoserver?

consider this, I have 100 columns and if I want to select a specific style I need to see all of them to choose .

Comment: GeoServer will display the attributes in the order they are stored in the feature. - Styling will have no effect on the order - please [edit] your question to make it clearer what is not working for you (maybe a screenshot of the problem?)

Comment: where are you looking for the styles? GeoServer doesn't care about the order and may or may not honour it - It sounds like you need to fix the order in your client code

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a client side issue, you need to apply a sort function to the style names before you insert them into your client's GUI element.